# Upgrade to rails 6.1.7.1 does not recognize the ActionMailer subclass in environments config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, smtp, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-6.1

After upgrading our app from rails 5.2.8.1 to rails 6.1.7.1, the ActionMailer subclasses are not recognized in environments config.

This is the error we recieved: `uninitialized constant BulkMailer (NameError)`
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghjhi.jpg)

Here are the setup details:

config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :user_name => 'myname',
    :password => 'mypass',
    :domain => 'mydomain',
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain
  }
  
  BulkMailer.smtp_settings = {
    :user_name => 'myname',
    :password => 'mypass',
    :domain => 'mydomain',
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain
  }
```

Bulk Mailer:

```
class BulkMailer < ApplicationMailer
...
end
```

ApplicationMailer:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
...
end
```

How can we resolve this issue?

Thank you!